# Reading Csv file with text as parameter in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, csvhelper

I have below code, where I am reading the csv file by passing the file path as parameter. the file is a valid csv file and i am able to read and do the necessary operation successfully. But now the requirement has changed and I will now be getting the CSV file contents as parameter instead of file path. I would like to know how can i modify the below method that gives me same result as my below function:

```
private IEnumerable<Dictionary<string,EntityProperty>> ReadCSV( string path, IEnumerable<TableField> cols )
    {
        using( TextReader reader = File.OpenText( path ) )
        {
            var cache = new TypeConverterCache();
            cache.AddConverter<float>( new CSVSingleConverter() );
            cache.AddConverter<double>( new CSVDoubleConverter() );
            var csv = new CsvReader( reader,
                new CsvHelper.Configuration.CsvConfiguration( System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture )
                {
                    Delimiter = ";",
                    HasHeaderRecord = true,
                    CultureInfo = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    TypeConverterCache = cache
                } );
            csv.Read();
            csv.ReadHeader();

            var map = (
            from col in cols
            from src in col.Sources()
            let index = csv.GetFieldIndex( src, isTryGet: true )
            where index != -1
            select new { col.Name, Index = index, Type = col.DataType }).ToList();

            while( csv.Read() )
            {
                yield return map.ToDictionary(
                    col => col.Name,
                    col => EntityProperty.CreateEntityPropertyFromObject( csv.GetField( col.Type, col.Index ) ) );
            }
        }
    }
```

and my TableField is class with below objects:

```
 public class TableField
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    ....and so on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have not tested it, but this should do the trick. Change the first few lines to look like this:

```
private IEnumerable<Dictionary<string,EntityProperty>> ReadCSV( string data, IEnumerable<TableField> cols )
    {
        using( TextReader reader = new StringReader(data) )
```